# ArcGIS web app builder near me find my location

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder, widget

Anybody know where to find this in the near me widget config?

[image]

I built my last version with it but now can't find the option to add it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When configuring the application, open up the widget configuration popup, and you will find it under the Search Settings tab, here:

[image: search settings tab, current location button highlighted]